# Allow only Nuget packages with verified package owners

Tags: nuget

Our dev servers at work currently can't reach nuget.org because of concerns about the safety of packages. Is it possible to apply a url rule / filter to a firewall that would allow access only to those packages with a "verified package owner"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with the server at this point. 
There's no APIs that would allow you to query whether a package has a verified owner or not. 
Additionally, the clients will hit so many different endpoints that it'd be very to make them all accessible. 
You'd need to whitelist almost all packages likely.

There is some work on the clients being done to cover your scenario though.

Along side with package signing, a new [client policies](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-NuGet-Package-Signing-Client-Policy) is being worked on. 
That would allow you only to accept packages from certain package authors/feeds.

An alternative in the short-term would be to use a mirroring feed that everyone in the company uses. 
That mirroring feed would only contain a set of whitelisted packages.